# Why Doesnt my 'AssertEquals()' method Fail?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

1. Why doesn't my assert method fail when the two strings clearly do not match?

   ```
   public void checkHomepageURL_Test1() throws Exception {
   basePage.loadHomePage();
   try {
       System.out.println("inside try block");
       Assert.assertEquals("Actual String Expected", "Im Wrong!");
       System.out.println("inside try block SECOND!!");




   } catch (Throwable e) {
       System.out.println("BETA!!!!!!" + e.getMessage());
   } finally {
       System.out.println("All over now!");
   }
   ```

   }

[image]

**New Examaple**
[image]

Comment: You can check [TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) named QMetry Automation Framework that provides [assert and verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) methods with detailed result in [report](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html).

Answer (score 1):

When an assert fails it throws an Throwable. Since you have your assert inside a try-catch block, when that Throwable is raised, it will be captured by the catch block, your program will log ""BETA!!!!!!" + e.getMessage()" and then it will finish properly.

You should either:

- remove your try catch block
- catch Exception instead of Throwable

(the first option is the proper one for a test AFAIK)

If you remove the Catch, your error will be printed as follows in your console.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Actual String Expected
Actual   :Im Wrong!
 <Click to see difference>


at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.scouto.test.checkHomepageURL_Test1(test.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: if i remove the try catch block, how would i output the assertion to the console window if its wrong?

Comment: That should be enough to check the reason of the failure and fix it. Otherwise you can rethrown it with throw (e); but I think this is a huge code smell

Comment: when i use TestNG Assert i seem to get the following listed in the image above

Comment: Never saw that library. I've always used org.junit.Assert and 
 org.junit.Test.

Comment: ok @SCouto if i use throwable it outputs the error to the console, Exception makes the test fail but dosnt output anything

Comment: As I said, you can always rethrow your throwable once it is cached.

} catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("BETA!!!!!!" + e.getMessage());
throw (e);
}

But its not really a good solution